SwiftUI, How to Implement a Dynamic Rearrangement of Widgets in a Grid-based Dashboard?
I'm trying to build a dashboard feature similar to the Aqara Home app, where widgets can be rearranged dynamically within a grid. My goal is to have widgets of varying sizes (defined by the number of grid cells they occupy) placed efficiently within the grid. The grid has a different number of columns depending on the device (4 columns for mobile, 8 for iPad).
Current Implementation:
I'm using a grid layout where each widget's size is defined by the number of cells it spans in width and height.
Widgets are currently arranged horizontally, and when there's no room left in the current row, they move to the next row.
I've implemented drag-and-drop functionality using onDrag and onDrop in SwiftUI.
Problem:
When dragging and dropping widgets, they are only arranged in horizontal rows. This leaves unused space in the grid, especially when widgets have different heights.
I want to implement dynamic rearrangement so that widgets can fill vertical gaps and make better use of the available space, similar to how the Aqara Home app allows widgets to snap into any available space, even between other widgets.
Question:
How can I efficiently implement the dynamic rearrangement of widgets in a grid-based dashboard in SwiftUI, where widgets can fill available space both horizontally and vertically? Are there best practices or patterns I should follow to achieve this?
Here's a simplified version of my code:

Widget:

class Widget: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var color: ColorData
    var position: Int
    var size: WidgetSize

    init(title: String, color: Color, position: Int, size: WidgetSize) {
        self.title = title
        self.color = ColorData(color: color)
        self.position = position
        self.size = size
    }
}

class WidgetSize: Codable {
    var width: Double
    var height: Double

    init(width: Double, height: Double) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
}


fake data:

var defaultDatas: [Widget] = [
      .init(title: "Widget 1", color: .red, position: 0, size: .init(width: 4, height: 2)),
      .init(title: "Widget 2", color: .orange, position: 1, size: .init(width: 2, height: 2)),
      .init(title: "Widget 3", color: .green, position: 2, size: .init(width: 2, height: 1)),
      .init(title: "Widget 4", color: .purple, position: 3, size: .init(width: 2, height: 1)),
      .init(title: "Widget 5", color: .cyan, position: 4, size: .init(width: 4, height: 1)),
      .init(title: "Widget 6", color: .pink, position: 5, size: .init(width: 1, height: 3)),
  ]


ViewModel

class DashboardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas: [Widget] = []

    var numberOfGrid: Double = UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? 4 : 8

    init() {
        let widgets = loadWidgetsFromUserDefaults()
        if widgets.isEmpty {
            datas = defaultDatas.sorted(by: { $0.position < $1.position })
        } else {
            datas = widgets.sorted(by: { $0.position < $1.position })
        }
    }

    func getMinimumWidth() -> CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / numberOfGrid
    }

    func saveWidgets() {
        let widgets = datas.enumerated().map { index, widget in
            print("AAA name: \(widget.title) - position: \(index)")
            return Widget(title: widget.title, color: widget.color.color, position: index, size: widget.size)
        }
        saveWidgetsToUserDefaults(widgets: widgets)
        datas = widgets
    }
}


Dashboard:

struct DashboardView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = DashboardViewModel()
    @State private var draggedItem: Widget?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(0 ..< self.calculateRows().count, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 8) {
                        ForEach(self.calculateRows()[rowIndex], id: \.id) { widget in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(widget.color.color)
                                .frame(width: CGFloat(widget.size.width) * vm.getMinimumWidth(),
                                       height: CGFloat(widget.size.height) * vm.getMinimumWidth())
                                .overlay(Text(widget.title).foregroundColor(.white))
                                .onDrag {
                                    self.draggedItem = widget
                                    return NSItemProvider(object: String(widget.title) as NSString)
                                }.onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropDeviceDelegate(currentWidget: widget, vm: vm, draggedWidget: $draggedItem))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }

    private func calculateRows() -> [[Widget]] {
        var grid: [[Widget]] = []
        var currentRow: [Widget] = []
        var remainingWidth = vm.numberOfGrid
        var maxHeightInRow = 0.0

        for widget in vm.datas {
            if widget.size.width > remainingWidth {
                if remainingWidth > 0 && widget.size.height <= maxHeightInRow {
                    if let lastWidgetInRow = currentRow.last, remainingWidth >= widget.size.width {
                        currentRow.append(widget)
                        remainingWidth -= widget.size.width
                    } else {
                        grid.append(currentRow)
                        currentRow = [widget]
                        remainingWidth = vm.numberOfGrid - widget.size.width
                        maxHeightInRow = widget.size.height
                    }
                } else {
                    grid.append(currentRow)
                    currentRow = [widget]
                    remainingWidth = vm.numberOfGrid - widget.size.width
                    maxHeightInRow = widget.size.height
                }
            } else {
                currentRow.append(widget)
                remainingWidth -= widget.size.width
                maxHeightInRow = max(maxHeightInRow, widget.size.height)
            }
        }

        if !currentRow.isEmpty {
            grid.append(currentRow)
        }

        return grid
    }
}

struct DropDeviceDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let currentWidget: Widget
    @ObservedObject var vm: DashboardViewModel
    @Binding var draggedWidget: Widget?

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let draggedWidget = draggedWidget else { return false }

        withAnimation(Animation.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.7, blendDuration: 1)) {
            let fromIndex = vm.datas.firstIndex { $0.id == draggedWidget.id }!
            let toIndex = vm.datas.firstIndex { $0.id == currentWidget.id }!

            if fromIndex != toIndex {
                vm.datas.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: fromIndex), toOffset: toIndex > fromIndex ? toIndex + 1 : toIndex)
            }
        }
        self.draggedWidget = nil
        vm.saveWidgets()
        return true
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        guard let draggedWidget = draggedWidget else { return }

        withAnimation(Animation.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.7, blendDuration: 1)) {
            let fromIndex = vm.datas.firstIndex { $0.id == draggedWidget.id }!
            let toIndex = vm.datas.firstIndex { $0.id == currentWidget.id }!

            if fromIndex != toIndex {
                vm.datas.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: fromIndex), toOffset: toIndex > fromIndex ? toIndex + 1 : toIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        withAnimation(.bouncy) {
            DropProposal(operation: .move)
        }
    }
}


What I’ve Tried:
I've written a calculateRows() function to organize the widgets into rows, but it doesn't optimize the grid's vertical space as needed.
Drag and drop work, but the rearrangement logic is still not right.

A custom Layout might be a way to solve.
